# Qual linguagem de programação utiliza essa Sintaxe?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber qual linguagem utiliza esta sintaxe? Estava dentro de uma tag `<h1>` de um HTML.

> ```
> {{app.settings.pagetitle}}
> ```

Os arquivos estão em sua maioria salvos em HTML, e eu preciso utilizar PHP para conectar com o SQL Server para puxar os dados das tabelas que serão exibidas no site, mas quando eu salvo o arquivo em PHP ele não abre nada.

Alguma ideia do que fazer?

Comment: Eu diria que esta em handlebars mas a extensão seria hbs, sendo assim, deve ser angularjs

Comment: Oi Kcpirola89, que framework esta usando?

Answer (score 12):

Há diversas linguagens (na verdade ferramentas de templates) que usam essa notação:

- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)
- [DoT](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html)
- ...

Observe que todas elas são ferramentas de templating. Muitas vezes são otimizadas para gerar código HTML. A maioria delas roda em cima do Javascript.